# How to query a neighbor vertex, which has certain attributes?

Tags: sql, graph, orientdb

Im using OrientDB 2.0. The query is simple, but I cant seem to figure it out. I have 2 classes: `User` and `UserGroup`. To make it simple, `User` has only `username` and `password` properties and UserGroup has only one `id` property. Relationship is simple:

`User --- user_group --> UserGroup`

where `user_group` is a class nam of edges connecting `User` and `UserGroup` vertices.

What I would like is to do is get a user with certain username and password where `UserGroup.id` is equal to *group1*

What I have so far is:

```
select expand(in('user_group')[username='foo' and password='bar']) 
from UserGroup
where id = 'group1'
```

But that does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create class User extends V
create property User.username string
create property User.password string

create class UserGroup extends V
create property UserGroup.id string

create class user_group extends E


create vertex User set username = 'foo', password = 'bar'
create vertex UserGroup set id = 'group1'

create edge user_group from (select from User where username = 'foo') to (select from UserGroup where id = 'group1')


select expand(in('user_group')[username='foo'][password='bar']) 
from UserGroup
where id = 'group1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, after a couple of tries, I found the answer:

```
select from 
   (select expand(in('user_group'))
    from UserGroup
    where id = 'group1')
where username='foo' and password='bar'
```

If anyone can suggest a more elegant solution, that would be nice too

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
from (
     select expand(in('user_group')) 
     from UserGroup 
     where id = 'group1'
) 
where username='foo' and password='bar'
```